# Сочетание прямой речи с подуманным, но то ли сказанным, то ли нет

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

> Мы скорбно и молча поднялись наверх, пошли по краю большого бассейна,
>   а тут нам навстречу усталые «ребята» – тренеры и вместо приветствия
>   говорят: «Раздевайтесь давайте. Полезайте-ка в воду, поплавайте». Мы
>   опешили. В смысле? Как так? С дельфинами? У меня и купальника-то нет…
>   Они отвечают: «Сейчас всё придумаем. Пошли».

Возможно ли "они отвечают" на непроизнесённое?

Comment: @Галина, я вас правильно понял: вас интересуют кавычки при внутренней речи?

Comment: Речь-то, понятное дело, внутренняя, но - от двоих *(мы опешили).* Мне нравится ("смотрится") без кавычек. Смущает, что "они" отвечают вслух на мысли...

Comment: Галина, внутренняя речь - это слова, которые произносятся в голове. Но ведь здесь автор в мыслях не произносил "Мы опешили". Это описывается реакция на предложение поплавать. Остальное: "В смысле? Как так? С дельфинами? У меня и купальника-то нет…"  он скорее произнес вслух,   они -то и ответили.  Почему вы думаете, что это мысли вслух?

Comment: Сержинька! У меня *отвечают вслух на мысли*, это совсем не то же самое, что *мысли вслух*. **ВСЛУХ**, нареч. *Так, что слышно другим, громко*.

Comment: Я о том же: "Мы опешили" - это не внутренняя речь, автор рассказывает о реакции.  Далее: слова: "В смысле? Как так?" автор мог произнести вслух. Почему вы считаете, что это внутренняя речь?

Comment: Зачем мне считать? Так в оригинале. Это непроизнесённое.

Comment: Галина,мне просто интересно,  из чего это видно? Просто из того отрывка, который вы привели, не ясно, что это внутренняя речь.

Comment: А у меня в вопросе и нет слов "внутренняя речь", это Вы предложили мне так именовать то, что я обозначила как *подуманное, но то ли сказанное, то ли нет*... Я в теории-то не сильна, исключительный практик!

Comment: Галина, внутренняя речь - это то, что вы называете: "подуманное"

Comment: Мерсю! Я все вопросы с ответами и комментами переправляю автору - пусть думает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подуманное, но то ли сказанное, то ли  нет, всё равно чужая речь и оформляется как прямая речь, т.е.  в кавычках, или диалог. Без кавычек  - только когда неизвестно, кому принадлежат слова, кто-то там сказал, а здесь известно - один из указанных героев. При желании можно слова разделить: один одно сказал, другой другое.

Варианты:

1. Мы скорбно и молча поднялись наверх, пошли по краю большого бассейна, а тут нам навстречу усталые «ребята» – тренеры и вместо приветствия говорят: «Раздевайтесь давайте. Полезайте-ка в воду, поплавайте». Мы опешили. "В смысле? Как так? С дельфинами? У меня и купальника-то нет…"  Они отвечают: «Сейчас всё придумаем. Пошли».
2. Мы скорбно и молча поднялись наверх, пошли по краю большого бассейна, а тут нам навстречу усталые «ребята» – тренеры и вместо приветствия говорят:

– Раздевайтесь давайте. Полезайте-ка в воду, поплавайте.

Мы опешили.

– В смысле? Как так? С дельфинами? У меня и купальника-то нет…

Они отвечают:

– Сейчас всё придумаем. Пошли.

3. Мы скорбно и молча поднялись наверх, пошли по краю большого бассейна, а тут нам навстречу усталые «ребята» – тренеры и вместо приветствия говорят:

– Раздевайтесь давайте. Полезайте-ка в воду, поплавайте.

Мы опешили.

– В смысле? Как так? С дельфинами?

– У меня и купальника-то нет…

Они отвечают:

– Сейчас всё придумаем. Пошли.

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, не "склеивается".

"«ребята» - тренеры"(?). Стоит тире, не дефис, но предложение не заканчивается. (§ 168. Тире ставится перед приложением, стоящим в конце предложения). Так может поставить тире с двух сторон: "«ребята» - тренеры - "

"**Мы** опешили", но "У **меня** и купальника-то нет."

Раз тренеры узнали, что купальника нет , значит это было сказано вслух. А раз так, должно быть подано как прямая речь.

Answer (score 2):

Вас смущает, что *слова не сказаны,* а на них кто-то *реагирует?*

Может быть, так:
*...Мы опешили. В смысле? Как так? С дельфинами? У меня и купальника-то нет… **На нашу растерянность** (нерешительность, заминку, смущение) **они отвечают:** «Сейчас всё придумаем. Пошли».*

Или:
*...Мы опешили. В смысле? Как так? С дельфинами? У меня и купальника-то нет… **Видя нашу растерянность** (нерешительность, заминку, смущение), **они предлагают:** «Сейчас всё придумаем. Пошли».*

И мысли остались "при себе", и молчаливая заминка понятна, и реакция на неё -  тоже.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Кстати, можно и **состояние "опешенности"** подкорректировать:

***...Мы опешили: в смысле? как так? с дельфинами? у меня и купальника-то нет…***

"*Мы опешили:*" - с двоеточием хорошо понятно, что *думает* не один человек.
Мне кажется, что ТАК даже красивее и читабельнее.

Comment: Общение с дельфинами развивает телепатические способности. Всё нормально.